# Backbone: how to test preventDefault to be called without testing directly the callback

Tags: testing, backbone.js, coffeescript, functional-testing, preventdefault

Let's say we have a simple Backbone View, like this:

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View

    events: 
        'click .save': 'onSave'

    onSave: (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()

        # do something interesting
```

I want to test that `event.preventDefault()` gets called when I `click` on my element with the `.save` class.

I could test the implementation of my callback function, pretty much like this (Mocha + Sinon.js):

```
it 'prevents default submission', ->
    myView.onSave()

    myView.args[0][0].preventDefault.called.should.be.true
```

I don't think it's working but this is only to get the idea; writing the proper code, this works. My problem here is that this way I'm testing the implementation and not the functionality.

So, my question really is: how can I verify , supposing to trigger a `click` event on my `.save` element?

```
it 'prevents default submission', ->
    myView.$('.save').click()

    # assertion here ??
```

Thanks as always :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a listener on the view's `$el`, then triggering `click` on `.save`, then verify the event hasn't bubbled up to the view's element.

```
var view = new MyView();
var called = false;
function callback() { called = true; }

view.render();

// Attach a listener on the view's element
view.$el.on('click', callback);

// Test
view.$('.save').trigger('click');

// Verify
expect(called).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: Do you think that would make sense here to insert some dummy elements to run a similar test? Like adding `<div class='myfoothatexistsonlyhere'><div class='.save'></div></div>` and then add the click event with your callback on `myfoothatexistsonlyhere`?

Reading your code, my first thought is "what if it's not bubbling up for some other reason?" like if another part calls `preventDefault`. Would that be overkill in your opinion?

Comment: Essentially, that's what this test *should* be doing. Rendering the view should setup a structure similar to what you've laid out. If you want, you could drop the rendered view into another parent element, but yes, that seems to me like overkill.

Comment: What I meant was adding these dummy elements after the view is rendered so that you don't rely on your actual template's structure and hope that no other event callback stops the bubbling. E.g. if your template had `div.container > div.willstopeverything > div.save` and `click .willstopeverything` is listened to somewhere else in your app without you realizing.

Comment: I see.If the structure and behavior of the view is as you suggested I'd configure my test to listen on the `.willstopeverything` div rather than the view's `$el`. One thing I would not do is override the view's template (or rendered HTML) as part of my test.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to test that `preventDefault` is called when a `click` event is generated, correct?

Couldn't you do something like (in JavaScript. I'll leave the CoffeeScript as an exercise ;)):

```
var preventDefaultSpy;

before(function() {
  preventDefaultSpy = sinon.spy(Event.prototype, 'preventDefault');
});

after(function() {
  preventDefaultSpy.restore();
});

it('should call "preventDefault"', function() {
  myView.$('.save').click();
  expect(preventDefaultSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
});
```

You might want to call `preventDefaultSpy.reset()` just before creating the click event so the call count is not affected by other things going on.

I haven't tested it, but I believe it would work.

edit: in other words, since my answer is not that different from a part of your question: I think your first approach is ok. By spying on `Event.prototype` you don't call `myView` so it's acting more as a black box, which might alleviate some of your concerns.

Comment: While this should work fine, it relies on the implementation to verify the behavior.